# is this kind of request possible in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

i have a problem with a asp.net website first i will explain the current situation:

my website display a table of elements, which i get over a webservice. to show the user always the actual elements i have a auto refresh in the site which refresh it every 10 seconds.

now i want to improve this, i want to get notified when there is new data and the page should be refreshed, is this possible?

in a further step i want to get notified and refresh the data (maybe with ajax?) without a whole refresh of the site. is this possible?

can somebody explain me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AJAX calling a web service method that returns the latest data.

You can call this AJAX method using `setTimeout`.

Comment: okay, but anyway i want to use this service which notificates me when i have new data

Comment: @gurehbgui - Long polling through AJAX is the only way, as HTTP is stateless.

Comment: http is but i'm using asp.net in the background. also not possible?

Comment: @gurehbgui - And how are you going to be talking to the server?